# Can't install vue ui on laravel 7.5.2

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'm trying to install Vue on Laravel 7.5.2.

I firstly run

```
composer require laravel/ui --dev
```

which gives me the following:

```
Using version ^2.0 for laravel/ui
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
Writing lock file
Generating optimized autoload files
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> @php artisan package:discover --ansi
Discovered Package: facade/ignition
Discovered Package: fideloper/proxy
Discovered Package: fruitcake/laravel-cors
Discovered Package: laravel-frontend-presets/tailwindcss
Discovered Package: laravel/tinker
Discovered Package: laravel/ui
Discovered Package: nesbot/carbon
Discovered Package: nunomaduro/collision
Package manifest generated successfully.
```

Then, when I try to run

```
php artisan ui vue
```

I get this error:

```
 ErrorException 



copy(/home/cornel/code/mogul-do/resources/sass/_variables.scss): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

  at vendor/laravel/ui/src/Presets/Bootstrap.php:42
    38|      * @return void
    39|      */
    40|     protected static function updateSass()
    41|     {
  > 42|         copy(__DIR__.'/bootstrap-stubs/_variables.scss', resource_path('sass/_variables.scss'));
    43|         copy(__DIR__.'/bootstrap-stubs/app.scss', resource_path('sass/app.scss'));
    44|     }
    45| 
    46|     /**

      +18 vendor frames 
  19  artisan:37
      Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
```

I've noticed that I don't have an assets folder in resources, could this have something to do with the issue? Also, I have no sass folder under resources if that is what it's looking for?

Comment: you need to  run npm install, vue should come by default

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed this by simply creating a resources/sass folder, no need to generate any files in that, the following command will do it automatically:

```
php artisan ui vue
```

Comment: As well as resources/js folder for me